# Difference of Roots Limit at Infinity

Tags: limits

lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{n^2 + 6b} - \sqrt{n^2 - n})$

Applying Limit Laws:

= ((lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{n^2}$ )+(lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{6b}$ )) - ((lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{n^2}$ )-(lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{n}$ ))

= (lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{6b}$ )) + (lim n -> ∞ $(\sqrt{n}$ ))

= 6b $(\sqrt{n}$ )

= 6b$(\sqrt{∞}$ )

= ∞

However when I check this example on wolfram I get lim n -> ∞ = ${\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Do you think that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$? I'm sorry, but nothing in your attempt is salvageable.

Comment: @egreg if you write it as $(a + b)^1/2$ then it is $(a^1/2 + b^1/2)$

Comment: $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}=2$. Uhm, something's amiss.

Comment: You need to go over your high school math textbook and/or notes. You need to fill in the gaps in the basics before starting calculus

Comment: @sawreals2 Writing it as $(a+b)^{1/2}=a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}$ does not make it true. It is not true. The square root is not a linear operation. Only linear operations distribute over addition. The only thing that does this is multiplication, differentiation, integration, and a few other well known linear operators. Square roots, powers, logs, trig functions, reciprocals, absolute values DO NOT DO THIS!

Comment: Use *\implies* or *\Rightarrow* if you want to generate $\implies$ or $\Rightarrow$. But specifically for limits, you can use *\to* or *\rightarrow* to generate $\to$ or $\rightarrow$ even though they are identical. For a longer arrow, you could write *\longrightarrow* which generates $\longrightarrow$

Comment: @sawreals2 If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, by  [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series)

$$x\to 0 \quad\quad(1+x)^\frac12 = 1 + \tfrac{1}{2}x+o(x)$$

we obtain

$$\sqrt{n^2 + 6b}=\sqrt {n^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{6b}{n^2}}=n\left(1+\frac{3b}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=n+\frac{3b}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$\sqrt{n^2 -n}=\sqrt {n^2}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}}=n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=n-\frac12+o(1)$$

thus

$$\sqrt{n^2 + 6b} - \sqrt{n^2 - n}=n+\frac{3b}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-n+\frac12+o(1)=\frac12+o(1)\to\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt{n^2+6b}-\sqrt{n^2-n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2+6b-(n^2-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{6b+n}{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}=\\ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{6b}{n}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{6b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{0+1}{\sqrt{1+0}+\sqrt{1-0}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: What law have you applied here?

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}= \frac{lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)}{lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)}$ and that for addition of limits  and simple algebraic transformations.

Comment: How can you apply this if there is no division?

Comment: Look at the first equality, on the right hand side there is a division.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am failing to see where the division is.

Comment: I meant the right hand side. i.e.$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2+6b-(n^2-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but your attempt is a disaster.

First of all, you cannot do
$$
\sqrt{n^2+6b}=\sqrt{n^2}+\sqrt{6b}
$$
for the simple reason it's false, unless $b=0$. Think to $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{1+1}$ and $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1}=2$. Do you agree that $\sqrt{2}\ne2$?

Next, no law of limit allows you to split that limit, because it's in the so-called “indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$”. You need to transform the sequence so that the limit can be computed; a good strategy is to write
$$
\textstyle\sqrt{n^2+6b}-\sqrt{n^2-n}=
(\sqrt{n^2+6b}-\sqrt{n^2-n})\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}
$$
(recall $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$) that becomes
$$
\frac{(n^2+6b)-(n^2-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+6b}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}
=
\frac{n\left(1+\dfrac{6b}{n}\right)}
{n\left(\sqrt{1+\dfrac{6b}{n^2}}+\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{n}}\right)}
$$
You can now simplify $n$ and apply limit laws.

Comment: I just don't understand how the quotient rule is applied if there is no division in the original limit I posted.

Comment: @sawreals2 The trick is to note that $a=\frac{ab}{b}$, and to choose a suitable $b$, like I did.

Comment: How do know when to apply this trick? Wouldn't b just cancel out?

Comment: @sawreals2 This is basic stuff (and pretty boring, too). You should have a thorough review of those basics.

Comment: Did you factor out n or $n^2$ in the last part? How is 6b/n^2? and 1/n?

Comment: @sawreals2  You.  Are. Not. Ready. For. Calculus.  Slower is faster:  Go back and learn algebra now, instead of failing calculus and learning algebra next Fall.

Comment: Oh wait it's because of the square root.. It's just been a while since I've done math last.